# Лишнее слово во фразе Сталина?

Tags: синтаксис

В книге Юлиана Семёнова "Ненаписанные романы" на 154 странице приводится стенограмма выступления Сталина на февральско-мартовском пленуме ЦК ВКП(б) 1937 года (с вероятностью 99.99%). В стенограмме есть такие слова: "Трижды возвращали проект в Наркомтяж. Трижды получали от Наркомтяжа **все** разные проекты".

Как правильно читается: *все* или *всё*? Нужно ли вообще это *все*/*всё* на ваш взгляд? Лично мне оно режет слух как вообще совершенно лишнее слово, а если предположить, что оно не лишнее, то мой разум теряется в догадках, как правильнее: *все* или *всё*?

П.С. В найденных в интернете стенограммах этого года почему-то нет этих слов Сталина; правда ли это вообще (у Ю. Семенова), или как так получается, что стенограмма Ю.Семёнова и стенограммы, найденные в интернете, разнятся?

**Дополнение:** на мой взгляд куда красивее и лаконичней просто: "Трижды получали от Наркомтяжа разные проекты". Или на крайний случай "всё разные проекты". 
Отсутсвие самих точек над е меня не смущало, смущало другое - то, что в тексте практически всегда интуитивно понятно, когда е, когда ё, а здесь полная несуразица была.

Comment: «Получали все разные проекты» — не по-русски. Бессмыслица. Как и «рознятся и веростностью».

Comment: а что не так с вероЯтностью?)

Comment: *на мой взгляд куда красивее и лаконичней просто* - это на Ваш взгляд. А реально ваши варианты хуже. Один слишком академичный, а второй (со "всё") - напротив, не очень грамотный.

Answer (score 1):

Нормально здесь всё. *"Вс**е**", не "всё"*. **Все проекты - разные**. Их более двух, видимо, и они все разные. Нет двух одинаковых.
Это, возможно, не самый высокий стиль, но вполне по-русски.
Тут недавно обсуждалось, почему говорят "оба разные", так и то большинство высказалось, что это нормально (хотя в этом случае как раз есть вопросы).
Так почему в отношении "все разные" возникает сомнение?!

Comment: Что один специалист в вопросах языкознания напутал, десяти умникам не распутать.

Comment: @М_Г Оно, конечгл, так, но не для данного случая. Здесь-то все (как по мне) достаточно понятно и правильно.

Comment: Согласен, что "всё" совсем неуместно, не согласуется с "трижды". Если всё получали да получали проекты, то почему "трижды"? С трудом, но смог принять "все", но это ужасный стиль, по-моему. Худший вариант разговорного.

Comment: @М_Г Я про "всё" ничего не говорила.

Comment: Как понимать ваше: "Все", не "всё"? Вы утверждаете, что  "всё" неуместно, не так ли? И я с вами согласен.

Comment: Да просто то что все проекты разные исходит из самого текста. Не могли ж ему одинаковые проекты приносить) Потому и вопрос к чему это все-всё вообще нужно. Или это просто так у Сталина было, так и записали.

Comment: @AlexanderGorlov Так это по стилистике вопрос или по грамматике? За Сталиным всё записывали до буквы, не сомневайтесь. А если что и правили потом, так с его согласия.Что до ваших разговоров про контекст, то я их просто не понимаю. Да, из текста что-то там "исходит". Но к чему это тут?

Comment: Вопрос исключительно по стилистике, разве что ещё как-то синтаксис сюда тоже приплести можно. В смысловой нагрузке (контекстом) уже дано понять, что все проекты разные - таким образом, при прочтении, возникает ощущение лишнего, ненужного слова, которое в данном случае все/всё. Все/всё здесь только потому, что оба можно поставить и подойдут. Смысл будет разный, но в обоих случаях ощущение "ненужности" останется.

Comment: @AlexanderGorlov *Вопрос исключительно по стилистике* Вопросы по стилистике меня не очень интересуют в плане обсуждения. Субъективно, а о вкусах не спорят. Но ответ я дала. ***Стилистика не нарушена.***

Answer (score 0):

Смысл понятен только в варианте "вс**ё** разные"; стилистически лучше переформулировать его в "(после возврата) трижды получали от Наркомтяжа проекты, и всё разные". Можно понять причины отсутствия *ё* в расшифровке стенограммы: обязательное применение этой буквы в школьном образовании было введено в 1942 году (на этом история употребления буквы не закончилась).

Comment: Как раз таки в вашем примере, больше подходит и лучше принимается "все" :): ...проекты, и все разные. А вот с тем, что у Сталина смысл понятен только с всё или ещё лучше без него согласен.

Comment: "Всё" акцентируется здесь не на слове "проекты": этим подчёркивается, что всякий раз из названных трёх "исправленный" (как ожидалось) проект в корне отличался от предыдущего ("белка песенки поёт да орешки **всё** грызёт" - здесь каждый из трёх раз **всё** та же картина, проект радикально изменён ) - всё новые да новые, с каждым разом непохожие на предшествующий. "Все" невразумительно и потому, что выражение "_получить трижды все проекты_" противоречит ранее названному факту: их возвращали _по одному трижды_. Это если исходить из того, что говоривший сам понимал, что говорит.

Comment: Согласен с вами - хорошее объяснение. Только вот ваша перформулировка (...проекты, и всё разные") по-прежнему оставляет ощущение какой-то неестественности. Как у Сталина (...Трижды получали от Наркомтяжа всё разные проекты) звучит ладней :) Теперь я практически уверовал, что "всё разные проекты" нормальный и хороший вариант (такие мысли и с самого начала были, но просто это редкая ситуация когда от Ё столь многое зависит!) :)

Answer (score 0):

В интернете есть эти слова Сталина (см. Заключительное слово на Пленуме ЦК ВКП(б) 5 марта 1937 года, https://www.marxists.org/russkij/stalin/t14/t14_43.htm)

Comment: М_Г, не надо комментировать в ответах. Используйте опцию комментариев или дополните вопрос.

Comment: (1) По-моему, это было частью вопроса (почему в интернете нет этих слов Сталина?) Ответ: есть эти слова в интернете.  
(2) Как можно дополнить вопрос? Пометить в скобках, что это моя вставка? Опыта нет. Научите.

Comment: М_Г - спасибо за ссылку. Гугл напрявлял на другой сайт, также с полной стенограммой, но там почему-то этого не было. И да, IrinaGL, это было частью вопроса.